# Reasoning with Pellet on SWRL rules in Jena Framework

Tags: jena, reasoning, pellet, swrl

I am trying to use Jena framework to edit an existing ontology built with Protoge 4.2. i.e. to change property values or add individuals or classes and then do reasoning. Assume in the ontology we have a rule such that: hasAge(?p,?age)^swrlb:greaterThan(?age,18)->Adult(?p). I would like to be able to change hasAge property on Jena side and see if someone is an Adult or not. Can you please provide me some sample code on this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that :

- you know how to populate your model by reading in the ontology that you built
- You have put Pellet on the classpath
- You replace the IRI's below with those from your domain
- You have assertions enabled

The following code snippet will add an age to an individual `x-test://individual` and assert that the property that would be introduced by SWIRL is satisfied.

```
// create an empty ontology model using Pellet spec
final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );   

// read the file
model.read( ont );

// Grab a resource and and property, and then set the property on that individual
final Resource Adult = ResourceFactory.createResource("x-domain://Adult");
final Property hasAge = ResourceFactory.createProperty("x-domain://hasAge");
final Resource res = model.createResource("x-test://individual");
res.addLiteral(hasAge, 19);

// Test that the swirl rule has executed
assert( res.hasProperty(RDF.type, Adult) );
```